# Cloning BitBucket in putty's SSH shell

Tags: ssh, git, putty

I had connected to Ubuntu machine in windows through putty's SSH client
assume the IP address is: `55.170.23.156`

I want to clone a Bitbucket repository inside this putty, assume the Bitbucket URL is `http://bitbucket.librariesdsw.net:8080/`

Assume Bitbucket username is `bharath` and the password is `welcome`

How to clone this Bitbucket repository inside this putty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About your question:

If the the Bitbucket Server base URL is `https://bitbucket.librariesdsw.net` and the SSH port is `8080`, the SSH URL for the repository `myRepo` in the project `myProject` will be:

`git clone git@bitbucket.librariesdsw.net:8080/myProject/myRepo.git`

If using HTTP, then the command will be:

`git clone http://Bharath@bitbucket.librariesdsw.net:8080/scm/dsw/dsw.g‌​‌​it`

With that address you can clone the repository, this works in putty, I tried it right now, so it should work for you.

Also, you can find more details in the documentation, here is the guide on [How to Clone a Repository on BitBucket](https://confluence.atlassian.com/get-started-with-bitbucket/clone-a-repository-861178563.html)

Also you can get the SSH URL or the HTTPS URL by browsing into the project and choosing SSH/HTTPS in the Overview of the Project, please see the image for a better reference:

[image: SSH URL]

If you still have problems getting the SSH URL, you can also clone the project using HTTPS.

Hope this helps, good luck!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71407/discussion-on-answer-by-galoget-cloning-bitbucket-in-puttys-ssh-shell).

Answer (score 0):

On you your bitbucket there must be a clone button , that provides a link , why dont you just go to the dir you want to use it a do a

```
git clone <your project-url>
```

am I missing something?